# Is replacing a natural gas cap with a quick-connect valve a task exclusively for a professional?

Tags: natural-gas

[image: natural gas cap]

Is there a specialized wrench that I should use on this cap to the natural gas line? I'd like to install a quick connect valve for a barbecue hose

More importantly, at the local big box store, the attendant (even though selling the parts) frowned when I suggested I'd be doing the install myself. Is this task really so tricky and/or so risky that an amateur should not attempt it?

Answer (score 1):

While the risks related to a leak are relatively low **for someone properly trained** , the fact that you might get your gas shut off by the town if the fittings havent' been tested and approved by their inspector means it's not worth that risk.

Answer (score 0):

Gasfitting is not rocket science given the right training and tools, but the consequences of getting it wrong are severe, to you and your house and potentially to your neighborhood. I really, *really* recommend letting a pro handle it; they have the proper pressure and leak testers, they have the experience, and they have the insurance.

Comment: There are serious risks, of course, with gas-fitting, but not quite as you're stating them. Natural gas (assuming mainly methane) is lighter than air, and so it will rise up in the atmosphere. Since we're talking about an outdoors fitting, the risk of an explosion is just about nil. Granted of course that no one would want to have gas leaking nearby, hence my question. We assume here that any potential leakage will not get carried by a draft indoors. Propane, incidentally, carries a bigger risk. Since it's heavier than air, it can potentially accumulate.

Answer (score 0):

Is the quick disconnect rated for natural gas? If so a standard pipe wrench is used with thread sealant rated for natural gas. The yellow PFTE tape rated for natural gas is one example. This is a very low pressure fitting. When building homes with natural gas the line is pressurized to 30 lbs and a gauge attached the inspector checks the gauge and all the appliances then rechecks the gauge if there is any pressure change you don't get your green tag to allow the Gas company to hook up the regulator (also all the venting and connections to appliances, shut off valves must pass inspection). I used to pressurize the systems at the end of the day and check them the next day when I got to the site. If the pressure held I would call for the inspection. Since this is outside a good bubble leak solution could be used but this is not as good as a pressure check.

Comment: I see now that my question was inherently subjective. Your skill level is obviously a lot higher than mine, and so the tasks that you can tackle with confidence are also significantly more difficult.